# Change paragraph on homepage from django admin panel

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to edit paragraphs on my homepage from the django admin panel. I tried making a "Homepage" class in models.py and calling it like so.

models.py

```
class Homepage(models.Model):
    homepage_image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    image_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    header_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    header_text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Homepage"

    def __str__(self):
        return "Homepage"
```

views.py

```
from .models import Homepage

# Create your views here.

def homepage_view(request):
    context = {
        "title": "Homepage",
        "homepage": Homepage.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, "main/index.html", context)
```

admin.py

```
from .models import Homepage

admin.site.register(Homepage)
```

index.html

```
  <p class="lead"> {{ homepage.header_text }} </p>
```

This may not be the ideal way to do this as in django admin I only want to have one "Homepage" that I can edit and swap out pictures from rather than having the add button.

Comment: Did you add the Homepage to `admin.py`? `admin.site.register(Homepage)`

Comment: Yes I did. I updated my post.

Comment: To be clear: are you asking for advice on design patterns, or are you facing an error message when trying to use your method? Basically... how can we help?

Comment: It wasn't giving me any error. I just couldn't render the paragraph text I specified in the admin panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fetch the first row from the DB, not just all objects, so that your template makes sense. Just change `.all()` to `.first()` and your template will work.

```
def homepage_view(request):
    context = {
        "title": "Homepage",
        "homepage": Homepage.objects.first()
    }
    return render(request, "main/index.html", context)
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great. I'll have to read about this because every tutorial said to use `all()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want just one static homepage, read about [flat pages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/flatpages/) in Django.

Also, you can take away the add permission from model using the [method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_add_permission) `has_add_permission` like so in your `admin.py`:

```
from .models import Homepage
from django.contrib import admin

class CustomHomepageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

admin.site.register(Homepage, CustomHomepageAdmin)
```

And in your `views.py`, change context to get a specific object:

```
def homepage_view(request):
    context = {
        "title": "Homepage",
        "homepage": Homepage.objects.get(pk=1) # Returns homepage with id 1
    }
    return render(request, "main/index.html", context)
```